# MySQL - Difference between Char and Varchar?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between VARCHAR and CHAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885630/whats-the-difference-between-varchar-and-char)

what is the difference between CHAR and VARCHAR.

Comment: Please, not another: [VARCHAR vs CHAR](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+char+vs+varchar)

Comment: Sadly, yes, we do not like [duplicates](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com+char+vs+varchar).

Comment: technically it wont be a duplicate if text is different.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a 1:1 copy to be duplicate.

Answer (score 64):

A CHAR field is a *fixed* length, and VARCHAR is a *variable* length field.

This means that the storage requirements are different - a CHAR always takes the same amount of space regardless of what you store, whereas the storage requirements for a VARCHAR vary depending on the specific string stored.

Comment: So why do we need to use CHAR ?

Comment: @HaykAramyan Because CHAR fields are stored inside the register due to its size being known, this makes searching and indexing faster. VARCHAR have to be stored elsewhere and reference tables have to be used to find the content.

Answer (score 9):

`VARCHAR` stores a variable number of bytes for only the space required by the content.

`CHAR` stores a fixed size of however many bytes you specify for your table, no matter how many characters occupy a field of this type per row.

Comment: so one ascii character is one byte?