# Examples of data types

Tags: sql, types, sqldatatypes

Suppose I have a column called doctorID and the ID consisted of string characters and numbers how do I know which data type to use?

Could I use CHAR(11) or would it be better to use VARCHAR(11) when answering this question could you please share some examples of when to use the data types?

Comment: What kind of database system is it?  Each database system has its own set of data types.

Answer (score 0):

@Anon.
[What's the difference between VARCHAR and CHAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885630/whats-the-difference-between-varchar-and-char)

> VARCHAR is variable-length.
>
> CHAR is fixed length.
>
> If your content is a fixed size, you'll get better performance with
>   CHAR.

If you use CHAR you may insert 5 chars in column CHAR(11) but after this 5 chars you'll have 6 whitespaces

Comment: How do you mean by performance? This meaning faster, reliable?

Comment: You didnt answer my 2nd question, would it be better to use CHAR(11) or VARCHAR(11) in my case, since the doctorID contains letters and numbers

Comment: If (char length of doctorID === 11) every time, char(11) is better. But if doctorID char length is sometimes < 11 Varchar(11) is better.