# Why CHAR and VARCHAR return the same length in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1886367/9500955), `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` return the length differently.

But when I run this [code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oV7VkTXsG4mFJVN36upzmh/0):

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
( ID            INT,
  Var_Name      VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  Char_Name     CHAR(5)    NOT NULL,
  Age           INT,
  Dnumber       INT,
  Level         INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, Var_Name, Char_Name, Age, Dnumber, Level) VALUES(1,'Tom', 'Tom', 21, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, Var_Name, Char_Name, Age, Dnumber, Level) VALUES(2,'Lucky', 'Lucky', 22, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, Var_Name, Char_Name, Age, Dnumber, Level) VALUES(3,'Blue', 'Blue', 20, 2, 3);

SELECT Var_Name, LENGTH(Var_Name), LENGTH(Char_Name) FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Output:

```
Var_Name    LENGTH(Var_Name)    LENGTH(Char_Name)
Tom         3                   3
Lucky       5                   5
Blue        4                   4
```

I think the output should like this:

```
Var_Name    LENGTH(Var_Name)    LENGTH(Char_Name)
Tom         3                   5
Lucky       5                   5
Blue        4                   5
```

Why `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` return the same length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html)

> The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255. When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the specified length. **When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are removed unless the PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH SQL mode is enabled.**

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2e91856be38aa17b24f4d4fc4c38119)